# No higher Cohomology for compact Riemann surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, sheaf-cohomology

If E is a holomorphic vector bundle on a compact Riemann surface X then

> Is it true that there are no non trivial sheaf Cohomology in dimensions ≥2?

By Dolbeaut theorem, this is true for $E=O_X$, the sheaf of holomorphic functions.

Comment: Do you know how to compute $H^k (X, E)$?

Comment: Of course. Can you help me with the question?

Comment: Note that the cohomology can be calculated by the complex $\cdots \Omega^{0,p}\otimes O(E) \overset{\bar \partial_E}{\to } \Omega^{0,p+1} \otimes O(E)\cdots$

Comment: Why is that? I was doing the same thing. But why do we know that this is an Injective/flasque resolution? I mean, why do we know that this resolution gives us sheaf Cohomology?

Comment: Well, the original Dolbeaut complex is a fine and hence acyclic resolution. So it gives us sheaf Cohomology. Perhaps you are saying that after tensoring it remains acyclic? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: If $E$ is a vector bundle, tensoring will be exact. Then $\Omega^{0,p} = 0$ for $p \geq 2$.

Answer (score -1):

**Question:** "Is it true that there are no non trivial sheaf Cohomology in dimensions ≥2?"

**Answer:** There is the vanishing theorem for cohomology of sheaves of abelian groups (of Grothendieck): If $C$ is a Noetherian topological space of dimension $n$ and $E$ is a sheaf of abelian groups on $X$ it follows $H^i(C,E)=0$ for all $i>n$. Hence if you view the sheaf cohomology of the corresponding sheaf of sections $E$ of your holomorphic vector bundle $\mathcal{E}$, and if $i:C^{alg} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ is an embedding realizing $C$ as an algebraic curve with the Zariski topology, the result follows since $H^i(C,E)=0$ for $i>1$.

**Note:** When $C$ is compact there is always a closed embedding $i$ realizing $C$ as an algebraic curve $C^{alg}\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$. You compare the cohomology of the sheaf of sections  $E$ and the corresponding locally trivial $\mathcal{O}_{C^{alg}}$-module $E^{alg}$: It follows (by Serre, GAGA theorems, see Hartshorne, Theorem App.B.2.1)

$$H^i(C,E) \cong H^i(C^{alg},E^{alg})=0.$$